# Create/Write Spreadsheet/Excel - How to loop EF Model/Table by row then cloumn without coulmn name

Tags: openxml-sdk

I am trying to create a generic method to export database tables to excel using Entity Framework and the Open XML SDK. I have the Open XML SDK code/method worked out, however when writing the data to XML I need to loop through each row by column. The challenge is (which usually is a benefit) the strongly typed column names. I can't figure out how to loop through each column of any table/model passed to the method. I tried Reflection getting the property names, however this returns more than just the actual table columns e.g. it also returns Navigation properties/related tables. Also, I would like to avoid Reflectionif possible, it is my understanding that it is not the most efficient/performance drag.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Code snippets below:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EF.NorthwindEntities db = new EF.NorthwindEntities();

        var custList = from c in db.Customers
                       select c;

        foreach (var row in custList) 
        {
            foreach (var col in row) // for (int i=0; > row.Length; i++)  Console.Write($"{col[i]}");
            {
                Console.Write($"{col}");
            }
        }

        foreach (var row in custList)
        {
            Console.Write($"{row.ContactName} { row.CompanyName} {row.Address} {row.City} {row.PostalCode}");
        }
    }
 }
```

**Open XML SDK code snippet:**

```
var columnNames = typeof(Customer).GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name).ToArray();

foreach (var c in columnNames)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new 
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(c);
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }


                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            foreach (var row in custList)
                {

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell1.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell1.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(row.CompanyName); //
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell1);

                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell2 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell2.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                        cell2.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(row.ContactName); //
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell2);

                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }
```

Comment: What does it output, can you include that in your question also?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862604/819019), it is possible without reflection if you are using [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/).  Try the [`GetProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.internal.entitytype.microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-ientitytype-getproperties?view=efcore-2.0) method:

```
var nonNavigationProperties = row.Metadata.GetProperties()
```

If this turns out to help you, I would add a tag to your question to include `entity-framework-core` (or `entity-framework-'X'` tag depending on which version you are using).  The tag will help get you more ef developers to help answer your question.